# How to limit the number of reps when parsing data in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, parsing

How to limit the number of reps to 10 times regardless of the **continuation**?

I tried to use until but apparently I didn’t understand it completely

```
def load_items
  url = "https://api.test.com/data#{self.account_address}"
  while url do
    data = HTTParty.get(url, timeout: 180, open_timeout: 1200, read_timeout: 120)
    json = data.dig('items')
    json.each do |item|
      unless self.items.where(item_id: item['id']).exists?
        begin
          item = Item.new(
            :item_id         => item['id'],
            :title           => item['title']
          )
          item.upsert
        rescue
        end
      end
    end

    url = if data['continuation']
      "https://api.test.com/data#{self.account_address}&continuation=" + data['continuation']
    else
      nil
    end
  end
end
```

I will be very grateful for the help

Comment: How about `10.times { ... break if !url ... }`.

Comment: _"number of reps"_ – what are "reps"? _"I tried to use until"_ – there's no `until` in your code.

Comment: @Stefan reps means repeats, yes there is no "until" in the code I wrote that I did not succeed

Comment: `while url do` will always be true until `url == false or url == nil`, so you need to use a different conditional structure or add some sort of break, throw, or exception flow control.